Unable to locate package php 7.0 in Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to install php 7.0, but I am getting this message on the WHM (WebHost Manager) terminal: Unable to locate package php 7.0 in Ubuntu 22.04.


To install php7+ you need to add the PPA ondrej/php,
Steps to add:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update,

then you simply do a sudo apt install php7.0 and php7 will be installed.
If you need any other version then simply add a php7.x and it'll be installed once you have added the PPA. Eg, sudo apt install php7.4
I did a quick google search and found that the ea-php7.0 package is not available on Ubuntu. You might want to try the php7.0 instead.
